# Bad Jump Destination

Tags: bad-jump, etherdelta

After I purchased PPT on etherdelta and my PPT was in my wallet, I pressed the wrong tab in order to exit etherdelta back to MEW. I realized my mistake and was able to export MEW out of etherdelta with my 28 tokens along with it. But  I did receive  this:

> Error encountered during contract execution [Bad jump destination]

I have not encountered this error warning since that exchange....Should I be concerned about this transaction? If so, what should I do about it?

Comment: Sorry, but you do not provide enough info to determine if something is wrong. You can check your wallet and balances are ok in a different browser or in a private tab.

Comment: Thank You Ismael for responding.I tried using another browser (chrome) to open my MEW and found no tokens in MEW. But I still see my tokens in MEW on my firefox browser.(I did all exchanges using firefox) I also opened my 2 other MEW's in chrome and they do show the correct amount of tokens inside them.

Comment: If the transaction was confirmed the PPT should be in your wallet. So there's the chance the transaction was not complete when you pressed the wrong tab. Check your wallet operations in etherscan.io to verify if there was a PPT transfer. Also you can try asking here https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherDelta/.

Comment: I went to  etherscan.io while I was in chrome and found that their was a transfer from etherdelta to MEW for 28 PPT and it did go thru. And I went to MEW in chrome and reinstalled the PPT as a custom token and I see all of my tokens now in my wallet. I hope I am out of the woods on this bad jump destination thingy.

Comment: If the transaction has failed will it be sent back to the original destination?

Answer (score 2):

"Bad jump destination" is a generic error message that means the transaction has failed.

The exact error depends on the contract and the operation. You have to check the contract and the parameters of the operation you are trying to complete.